# Python/Regex splitting a specifically formatted return string

Tags: python, regex

I'm working with a search&replace programming assignment. I'm a student and I'm finding the regex documentation a bit overwhelming (e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), so I'm hoping someone here could explain to me how to accomplish what I'm looking for.

I've used regex to get a list of strings from my document. They all look like this:

```
%@import fileName (regexStatement)
```

An actual example:

```
%@import script_example.py ( *out =(.|\n)*?return out)
```

Now, I'm wondering how I can split these up so I get the fileName and regexStatements as separate strings. I'd assume using a regex or string split function, but I'm not sure how to make it work on all kinds of variations of %@import fileName (regexstatement). Splitting using parentheses could hit the middle of the regex statement, or if a parentheses is part of the fileName, for instance. The assignment doesn't specify if it should only be able to import from python files, so I don't believe I can use ".py (" as a splitting point before the regex statement either.

I'm thinking something like a regex "%@import " to hit the gap after import, "\..* " to hit the gap after fileName. But I'm not sure how to get rid of the parentheses that encapsule the regex statement, or how to use all of it to actually split the string correctly so i have one variable storing fileName and one storing regexStatement for each entry in my list.

Thanks a lot for your attention!

Comment: Can the filename contain spaces?  If not, no need to use a regex.  Just split your string on spaces with maxsplit 2, take the second piece as the filename, and take the third piece as the regex (after trimming the parentheses).

Comment: @BrenBarn Oh, that could work. I'll try it. Never thought about maxsplit.

Comment: @BrenBarn
Do you know how to get the string out of a match object? I've ran 

    `textToImport = re.search(regexStatement, fileName)`
  
, but I'm not sure how to get the string out of textToImport (it's just a matchobject, and the documentation doesn't say as far as I can see).

Comment: to add to it, group(0) gets the first hit, but since len() doesn't work on a matchobject I'm not sure how to do it on every matched string.

Comment: This is yet another reason not to use a regex when you don't need to :-).  If you have questions about how to use regex match objects that you can't answer by looking at the documentation or other questions on StackOverflow, then you should probably ask a separate question about that, since it's tangential to the question here.

Comment: @BrenBarn Well this is a place where it was actually needed to use regex, as I'm searching an entire document to find a specific set of text to import, using said regexStatement. So there is actually a need to. I wasn't of the impression that going a bit tangential in the comments was a problem if it's solved? Well, ok.

Comment: It's okay to go a bit tangential, but it seems like you're really asking a separate question here about how to use a match object (which, as I pointed out in my answer, you don't need to do at all to solve the problem your question is asking about).

Comment: @BrenBarn Fair enough. I wouldn't call asking you to explain the syntax of your answer (below) tangential, though, as it's essential to understanding your answer (and not just mindlessly copypasting it) :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the filename can't contain spaces, just split your string on spaces with maxsplit 2:

```
>>> line.split(' ', 2)
['%@import', 'script_example.py', '( *out =(.|\n)*?return out)']
```

The maxsplit 2 makes it split only the first two spaces, and leave intact any spaces within the regex.  Now you have the filename as the second element and the regex as the third.  It's not clear from your statement whether the parentheses are part of the regex or not (i.e., as a capturing group).  If not, you can easily remove them by trimming the first and last characters from that part.

If you assign the values like this:

```
filename, regex = line.split(' ', 2)[1:]
```

then you can strip the parentheses with:

```
regex = regex[1:-1]
```

Comment: I'm testing this out now, and I will accept as soon as it works!

Comment: Great, that worked as far as splitting is concerned! That said I used regex, so my solution is re.split(r"\s", statement, 2) where statement is the string I'm splitting. How would you trim the parentheses, though?

Comment: @user2875994: See my edited answer.  Why did you want to use a regex if you can do it without one?

Comment: Well I'm mostly using regex so I get used to it. The assignment in general will use it a lot so I figured it'd make sense. Thanks for the edit! Accepting your answer now. That said, can you explain exactly how [1:-1] works? I'm assuming it's something like "remove the first and the last character", but what exactly is the syntax?

Comment: @user2875994: It means "slice the string from after the first character to before the last character".  Again, this is getting a bit tangential to your main question.  You should take a look at [the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#using-python-as-a-calculator)

Answer (score 0):

That should do it nicely

```
^%@import (\S+) \((.*)\)
```

or, if the filename may have spaces:

```
^%@import ((?:(?! \().)+) \((.*)\)
```

Both expressions contain two groups, one for the file name and one for the contents of the parentheses. Run in multiline mode on the entire file or in normal mode if you work with single lines anyway.

This: `((?:(?! \().)+)` breaks down as:

```
(             # group start
  (?:         #   non-capturing group
    (?!       #     negative look-ahead: a position NOT followed by
       \(     #       " ("
    )         #     end look-ahead
    .         #     match any char (this is part of the filename)
  )+          #   end non-capturing group, repeat
)             # end group
```

The other bits of the expression should be self-explanatory.

---

```
import re

line = "%@import script_example.py ( *out =(.|\\n)*?return out)"
pattern = r'^%@import (\S+) \((.*)\)'

match = re.match(pattern, line)

if match:
   print "match.group(1) '" + match.group(1) + "'"
   print "match.group(2) '" + match.group(2) + "'"
else:
   print "No match."
```

prints

```
match.group(1) 'script_example.py'
match.group(2) ' *out =(.|\n)*?return out'
```

Answer (score 0):

For matching something like `%@import script_example.py ( *out =(.|\n)*?return out)` i suggest :

```
r'%@impor[\w\W ]+'
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kA8pE8/2)

note that :

```
\w match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
\W match any non-word character [^a-zA-Z0-9_]
```

so you can use `re.findall()` for find all the matches :

```
import re
re.findall(r'%@impor[\w\W ]+', your_string)
```

Comment: I already found the strings, that's not the problem I'm asking about :) If you were wondering the regex statement I use it is     r"%@import.*".

Comment: str.startswith only tests the beginning of a specific string as far as I know, so that wouldn't work :)